# Read data from a DDSU666 using RS485

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial, modbus, rs485

I have tried my luck with these codes to read the data from the DDSU666-H and it seems that I am able to read data, but I don't know what to do with it. In theory it is a list of data, but I am not able to understand what I am receiving or how to translate it into something I can use

```
import serial                          # import the module

def banner_bottom():
    print('   +-------------------------------------------+')
    print('   |                    SPACE                  |')
    print('   +-------------------------------------------+')

COM_Port = serial.Serial('COM3')
COM_Port.baudrate = 9600               # set Baud rate 
COM_Port.bytesize = 8                  # Number of data bits = 8
COM_Port.parity   = 'N'                # No parity
COM_Port.stopbits = 1                  # Number of Stop bits = 1
COM_Port.setRTS(1) #RTS=1,~RTS=0 so ~RE=0,Receive mode enabled for MAX485
COM_Port.setDTR(1) #DTR=1,~DTR=0 so  DE=0,(In FT232 RTS and DTR pins are inverted)
                   #~RE and DE LED's on USB2SERIAL board will be off
RxedData = COM_Port.readline()
print('   ',RxedData, '\n')

COM_Port.close()                       # Close the Serial port

banner_bottom()# Display the bottom banner
```

Output:

```
b'\x7f~\xbb\xff\xfb\xe3=\x7f~_cuI_\x0e\x7f~\xbb\xff\xfb\xe3=\x7f~_]\xd3V\'\t\x7f~\xbb\xff\xfb\xe3=\x7f~__\x07\xf5tU\x7f~\xbb\xff\xfb\xe3=\x7f~_[y\x8d\xba\x00\x7f~\xbb\xff\xfb\xe3=\x7f~_YsGe\x18\x7f~\xbb\xff\xfb\xe3=\x7f~_Y\xe3\x06n\x16\x7f~\xbb\xff\xfb\xe3=\x7f~__O]I\x1d\x7f~\xbb\xff\xfb\xe3=\x7f~_ao\xff\xf0\x05\x7f~\xbb\xff\xfb\xe3=\x7f~_co-O\x10\x7f~\xbb\xff\xfb\xe3=\x7f~__\x15\x117\x03\x7f~\xbb\xff\xfb\xe3=\x7f~__!-\xc9/\x7f~\xbb\xff\xfb\xe3=\x7f~__}\xed|\x00\x7f~\xbb\xff\xfb\xe3=\x7f~_c\xb7+\xda\x00\x7f~\xbb\xff\xfb\xe3=\x7f~_e\x8f"U\x01\x7f~\xfd\xff\xfb]\x1a\x7f~_W\xaf\x08\x975\x00\x7f~\xfd\xff\xfb]\x1a\x7f~_W\xaf\x08\x975\x00\x7f~\xfd\xff\xfb]\x1a\x7f~_W\xaf\x08\x975\x00\x7f~\xbb\xff\xfb\xe3=\x7f~_]\xd3V\'\t\x7f~\xbb\xff\xfb\xe3=\x7f~__\xd9\xadb\x08\x7f~\xbb\xff\xfb\xe3=\x7f~__\xc5[P\x05\x7f~\xbb\xff\xfb\xe3=\x7f~__\x91\xfef\x00\x7f~\xbb\xff\xfb\xe3=\x7f~_c3\xb3T\x0f\x7f~\xbb\xff\xfb\xe3=\x7f~_e\xbd\x01\xb0\x03\x7f~\xbb\xff\xfb\xe3=\x7f~_e?y\x84\x19\x7f~\xbb\xff\xfb\xe3=\x7f~_\xe349\xac\n'
```

Code 2:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import serial

port = 'COM3'
ComPort = serial.Serial(port)
ComPort.baudrate = 9600
ComPort.bitesize = 8
ComPort.parity = 'N'
ComPort.stopbits = 1
dataIn=ComPort.read(6)
print(dataIn)
ComPort.close()
```

Ouput:

```
b'\x7f~\xbb\xff\xfb\xe3'
```

I've tried to translate the output into something I can understand, but I haven't been able to see anything either.

```
binary_data = b'\x7f~\xbb\xff\xfb\xe3'
aa = binary_data.hex()
print(aa)
#OUT: 7f7ebbfffbe3
bb = ''.join(['%02x' % b for b in binary_data])
print(bb)
#OUT: 7f7ebbfffbe3
s = binary_data.decode('cp855')
print(s)
#OUT:~â•—Â Ñ‡Ñ
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Is it a modbus device? have you tried tools such as `modpoll` to verify the device?

Comment: I have not been able to receive a response using modpoll or any other program.  I only receive data when connected to an inverter.  I even tried with docklight.de and nothing

Comment: If your purpose is to get data and you confirm it is a modbus device, then you shall be able to get the register list from vendor and use a modbus tool to poll data, try [this](https://github.com/gavinying/modpoll) python tool.